# JBoss EAP7 ModelControllerClient connection refused on localhost

Tags: jboss

I am writing a JBoss EAR application that needs to query the local JBoss server it is running on for status of deployments. I am running JBoss as standalone. I am able to query the JBoss server easily using the JBoss-CLI, but using the API with the 'ModelControllerClient', I am getting a "connection refused" error. My firewall is completely disabled, and I am pointing at localhost, so I am not sure what the problem could be.

Here is the code I am running:

```
public static void GetStatus() throws Exception{

    ModelNode operation = new ModelNode();
    operation.get( "address" ).add( "deployment", "*" );
    operation.get( "operation" ).set( "read-attribute" );

    ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9990);
    ModelNode result = client.execute( new OperationBuilder(operation).build() );

    List<ModelNode> deployments = result.get( "result" ).asList();
    String deploymentName;

    // finally we can iterate and get the deployment names.
    for ( ModelNode deployment : deployments ) {
        deploymentName = deployment.get( "result" ).asString();
        System.out.println( "deploymentName = " + deploymentName );
    }
}
```

... and here is the error I receive when this method is called:

```
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
```

If I run the `netstat -tuna` command, I see that I am listening to `0:0:0:0:9990`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with starting server on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0. Also refer sample example from http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2676